# The meaning of relativization

Tags: complexity-theory, oracle-machines, relativization

I don't understand the notion of relativization. I expose with an example. Consider a class $A$ that contains $P$, e.g. $NP$. Why $P^A$ is not necessarily equal to $A$? I can naively think that if one can decide any problem in $A$, one can also decide any problem that uses polynomially many steps in a Turing machine plus calls to $A$. One can have at most polynomially many calls to $A$, thus $P^A$ seems there is only a polynomial overhead compare to $A$. If $A$ is $NP$, I could give a certification for all the (polinomially many) oracle calls, and also easily give a certification of the polynomial rest of the computation.
I understand that if it is true, then $NP$ is the same as $coNP$, both being contained in $P^{NP}$ from the polynomial hierarchy. So, where is the error in my naive argument?

Comment: Perhaps your source of confusion is that $P$ is **defined** to be the class of languages decided by deterministic polynomial time Turing machines, not the class of languages decided in polynomial time by "arbitrary machines". When you add an oracle to a polynomial-time Turing machine $M$, you get a machine $M'$ that is no more a "deterministic polynomial time Turing machine". In order to prove that $M'$ is in $P$ (or more formally that $M'$ decides a language in $P$), you must give an equivalent deterministic polynomial time TM $M''$ (with no oracles) that decides the same language of $M'$.

Answer (score 5):

Take $A=NP$, as you requested.  $P^{NP}$ is not necessarily equal to $NP$.

Let me give an example why not.  Consider TAUTOLOGY (given a boolean formula $\varphi$, is it true for all possible assignments to the variables?).  TAUTOLOGY is known to be co-NP-complete.  Therefore, TAUTOLOGY most likely is not in NP, since if TAUTOLOGY were in NP, it would follow that NP = co-NP, which is widely suspected not to be the case.

However, TAUTOLOGY is certainly in $P^{NP}$.  Here's why.  Given an oracle for SAT, we can solve TAUTOLOGY as follows: Given $\varphi$, query whether $\neg\varphi$ is in SAT; then flip the answer (if $\neg\varphi$ is in SAT, answer "no, $\varphi$ is not in TAUTOLOGY"; if $\neg\varphi$ is not in SAT, answer "yes, $\varphi$ is in TAUTOLOGY").  This shows how to solve TAUTOLOGY in polynomial time given an oracle for SAT, and SAT is in NP, so this shows that TAUTOLOGY is in $P^{NP}$.

So TAUTOLOGY is an example of a problem that is in $P^{NP}$, but probably isn't in NP (unless NP = co-NP).  Hopefully this helps illustrate why NP is not the same as $P^{NP}$.

If not, here's a little more intuition.  NP is a particular class.  $P^{NP}$ is the class of problems that can be solved by querying an oracle for NP, possibly many times.   The "many times" part is the key difference between NP and $P^{NP}$.  A (many-one) reduction between two NP problems can only query a NP-oracle once, while $P^{NP}$ allows you to query the oracle as many times as you like.  That seems to be a lot more powerful,  and it's the reason why $P^{NP}$ seems to be a bigger class than NP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is not the answer I was looking for. My tentative intuition was the same you gave: in P^NP I can query the NP oracle many time. But it is not convincing because in P^NP I can query at most polynomially many times the NP oracles, thus providing at most a polynomial overhead of complexity with respect to NP which does not really separate the two classes. Am I mistaken? In your example there is only one query to SAT, so it doesn't clarify the intuition.

Comment: Moreover, even if I tend to believe all these conjectures, like NP is different from co-NP, these are still conjectures and do not provide a proof.

Comment: @neophyte, of course it's not going to provide an unqualified proof.  Asking for an unqualified proof (with no unproved assumptions) is unreasonable.  If the polynomial hierarchy collapses, then $P^{NP} = NP$.  It's conjectured that the polynomial hierarchy doesn't collapse, but that's not known for sure.  Therefore there's no hope of an unqualified proof that $P^{NP} \ne NP$.

Comment: ok, but you haven't replied to my criticism on your intuition. can you, please?

Answer (score 2):

Why might $P^A$ not equal to $A$?

**$A$ might be weaker than $P$**

$P^A$ can't be weaker than $P$, but $A$ might be. For example, if $A$ is the complexity class of linear-time problems $O(n)$ then $P^A = P^{O(n)}=P$.

**$A$ might have different strengths than $P$**

For example, consider $B=O(1)^{3SAT}$ and $A=3Coloring$. The *only* problem $A$ can solve is 3-coloring. It can't solve 3-Sat. $B$ can solve 3-sat, and various constant time problems, but it can't solve 3-coloring because it doesn't have enough time to do so directly or to translate the problem into 3-sat.

On the other hand, $B^A = {O(1)^{3SAT}}^{3Coloring}$ can solve *both* 3-sat and 3-coloring, so it's stronger than either $A$ or $B$ individually.

In the case of $P$, a class with different strengths could be the class of problems that takes $O(n)$ space. Some problems in $P$ require more-than-linear space, and some problems that require $O(n)$ space use exponential time. So $P^{O(n) space}$ gains both the powers of $P$ and $O(n) space$, making it larger than either of them individually.

**$A$ and $P$ might synergize into something better**

For example, $P^{NP}$ can trivially solve $coNP$ problems, but it's suspected that $P \subset coNP$ and $NP \neq coNP$ and $(P \cup coNP) \not \subset coNP$.

This is even more striking if you think of it as $NP^{NP}$. Complexity classes don't have to be [low](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_%28complexity%29) for themselves.